# Quit SSIS Script task without error or anything

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis

You'd think you find such thing easily on google (or any other search provider) -> not.

I have a SSIS package that runs every 5min.
My package has an error routine in the onError event handler **but** I don't want it to get in there.

So in fact, the package should just exit / close / kill itself without any warning or error.
Preferably this should be initiated by the script task (vb.net 2008)

Thanks a lot in advance!
L

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. you want the package to exit after getting to the point where the script task is executed, regardless of the output?

Comment: If you have an error handling routine defined in the OnError event but you do not want that code executed, why don't you disable or even remove the OnError event? I'm certain I'm missing something in your question.

Comment: Thanks you. Sorry for my late comment (holidays), in fact: we wanted to use the OnError event for errors. With the Stop function, I also nicely see in the SQL job agent that the job was 'stopped by job request' (stop sign), effective runs have the green arrow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script task (vb.net):

```
RunningPackage.Stop()
```

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop.aspx#Y0

Comment: Thanks, this is it!      Dim app As Application = New Application() Dim pkgs As RunningPackages = app.GetRunningPackages("localhost")  Dim package As RunningPackage For Each package In pkgs package.Stop() Next